# iCloud photos don't show up in any editor

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

I am new to MacOS (Sierra). I used iOS and iCloud photos for quite a long time now but I wonder why I cannot open any photo from iCloud photo stream in an editor like Pixlr to edit it directly. I know the workaround but I wanted to know if this is intended and maybe if there is a setting that I missed so far. 
I'd like to open photos from my photo stream directly in any editor and program.

Comment: (iCloud) Photo Stream and iCloud Photos/iCloud Photo Library are two totally separate things. Which are you referring to?

Comment: I guess I am referring to the photo stream, the place where all my photos show up that I made e.g. with iPhone etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up Pixlr, and when you go to 'open', in your sidebar you should have a Media / Photos option.  If you click that it'll show your albums etc.  See the screenshot...

[image: Media/Photos dialog]

Comment: That's true, didn't see that entry - just the "Pictures" folder.